# Cannot force new deployment on ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy

I have an ECS service that uses CodeDeploy to make blue/green deployments. When I want deploy new code, I usually:

`navigate to the ECS console --> navigate to the service --> click Update --> check "Force new deployment" --> click Update Service`

This works fine, but if I do the same thing in the CLI:

`aws ecs update-service --cluster <my_cluster> --service <my_service> --force-new-deployment`

I get the error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the UpdateService operation: Cannot force a new deployment on services with a CODE_DEPLOY deployment controller. Use AWS CodeDeploy to trigger a new deployment.
```

Based on this error, my idea of a workaround is to:

1. Use the aws cli to create a task definition revision
2. Update the service with the new task definition

Which in theory should kick off a new deployment, but my gut tells me there's a more efficient way since I don't need to take those steps in the console.

Does anyone know of the right / better way to programmatically update code in my ECS cluster?

Thanks!

Comment: The error is clear. Somehow you setup up `AWS CodeDeploy` to manage deployments, not ECS.

Comment: @Marcin right, my ECS service uses AWS CodeDeploy to manage my deployments. But when i'm in the console, I can just update my ECS service and check `Force new deployment` instead of using the `AWS CodeDeploy` console to kick off a deployment, so my thought is I should also be able to kick off a deployment in the CLI without using `AWS CodeDeploy`

Comment: I think console will use CodeDeploy in the background. Just check if you can an active CD deployment, when you force the update in the ECS console.

Comment: If someone arrived here because they saw this error when trying to update via the console, turn off the "New ECS Experience" on the top left corner and then check "force new deploy" before saving.